# laravel Backpack Original Image Name

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel backpack for my site and i need to upload some images, i copy the code from their website and works fine, but i need the original name on the images, i tried some things, but is not working.

```
public function setImageAttribute($value)
{
    $attribute_name = "image";
    $disk = "uploads"; 
    $destination_path = 'storage/services/' .date('FY').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    if ($value==null) {
        Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$attribute_name});
        // set null in the database column
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = null;
    }
    if (str_starts_with($value, 'data:image'))
{
    $file = $value;
    $filename = $this->generateFileName($file, $destination_path);
    $image = InterventionImage::make($file)->orientate();
    $fullPath = $destination_path.$filename.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $fullPath;
}


protected function generateFileName($file, $destination_path)
{
        $filename = basename($file->getClientOriginalName(), '.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension());            
        $filename = Str::random(20);
        while (Storage::disk('uploads')->exists($destination_path.$filename.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension())) {
            $filename = Str::random(20);
        }
    return $filename;
}
```

why value alwys take image base64

is there any way to git image original name?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you won't be able to retrieve the filename, as it's always a base64 file. But maybe this work around helps you:

Image fields blade file can be found at:

> \vendor\backpack\crud\src\resources\views\crud\fields\image.blade.php

You can overwrite it by making a file on the same name at:

> \resources\views\vendor\backpack\crud\fields\image.blade.php

You can change anything there, maybe you can add a hidden input with the file name.